# How to get unique id of mobile xamarin c#?

Tags: c#, xamarin

i am trying to retrive a unique id of mobile using mobile xamarin application i am using in

```
MainActivity.Cs

public class AndroidDevice : IDevice
    {

        public string GetIdentifier()
        {
            var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            return Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
        }

}
```

and i created a Interface in shared project as

```
 public interface IDevice
    {
        string GetIdentifier();
    }
```

i called the function in shaed project as

```
string deviceIdentifier = DependencyService.Get<IDevice>().GetIdentifier();
```

i alawys get

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Comment: what is null?  Most likely your `DependencyService.Get()` call is returning null because it can't resolve the reference.  Have you followed all of the instructions in the DependencyService documentation?

Comment: string deviceIdentifier  is alawys null,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Dependency attribute to the assembly namespace where the class that implements the interface is declared.

Eg.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DroidImplementation))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Implementation
{
    public class DroidImplementation : IMyInterface
    {
       // your class implementation here
    }
}
```

I wouldn't add the class to the MainActivity.cs but create a separate namespace for that.